# Modify space between paragraphs and nothing else

Tags: paragraphs

**Edit**
If you prefer some additional space between paragraphs, you can't simply do

```
\setlength{\parskip}{<length>}
```

as this will also modify settings for list environments, the table of
contents,... headings.

The `parskip` package takes care of list environments and the table of
contents but not headings as can be seen in this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}%parskip}
\usepackage{eso-pic,tikz}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[blue!20!white,thin]
       (current page.south west) grid [xstep=10mm,ystep=4mm] (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

How can we change the amount of space between paragraphs without changing any thing else?

**Original question**
When I modify the usual `\parskip` it adds space to everything: formulas, titles,.. I want to change spacing only between paragraphs, not any other things. The `parskip` package does not help.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, but this is very unclear.

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: @egreg is it clear now?

Comment: @cfr This does not work.

Comment: Sorry but 'does not work' is not at all clear. How doesn't it work? Does your document not compile? Does your computer have a tantrum and refuse to get ready for bed? The `parskip` package is designed to do exactly what you say you want to do. Without an example or any sort of information at all, I obviously can have no idea in what way it fails to meet your requirements or why it does so. For all I know, you aren't even using LaTeX. That was just a guess. If not, obviously it won't work.

Comment: @egreg what i understand is that the OP want to change vertical space separete text paragraphs without changing sepacing of pargraphs used in chapter ans so like by the command `\par` used internely therein. when i read this question the first time it comes to me the answer: add vertical space manully.

Comment: @touhami yes, you understood it right. Then the question is is it possible to do by latex automatically, or I need to do it manually for all the paragraphs.

Comment: it may be possible for some one like @egreg. But you shoud edit your question before it will be closed

Comment: there is two way to end paragraph: with `\par` command or with blank line, the idea is redefine one of them to be slightly different

Comment: @cfr can you edit this question

Comment: @touhami Why don't you edit it? I'm not objecting to being asked: I'm just confused about what you want me to do. Shouldn't the OP edit it?

Comment: @user14416 The `parskip` package is designed to do just what the you seem to want. It makes adjustments so that the things which use `\parskip` for spacing don't all end up inserting too much vertical space when `\parskip` is set to a non-zero minimum. At least, that's how I understand its purpose. As far as I know, that's *the* reason to use `parskip` rather than setting `\parskip` & `\parindent` manually. Just saying it 'doesn't work' is not helpful. If you say in which specific ways it falls short, it might be possible to suggest additional changes to better realise your ideal.

Comment: @cfr you are right the OP should do but may be he don't know that the question will be closed soon, I can't edit because of my english.

Comment: @touhami If you want to edit it and ping me, I'll tidy up the English if you like. I think your English is pretty good anyway, but I'd be happy to check. I'm not sure how to edit the question because I don't understand why `parskip` doesn't work.

Comment: @cfr i will try to edit this question and indeed `parskip` doesn't answer the OP's need it change  spacing

Comment: @cfr i edit the question

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of this question: [How to change separation space between paragraphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240751)

Comment: @AlanMunn may be duplicated but the answers therein don't fill need here

Comment: @touhami Edited as promised... ;).

Comment: OK. So it isn't true that `parskip` 'doesn't help' which suggested to me that the problem was some completely different one. The issue is that the package does not solve all of the issues. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

See the [titlesec package documentation](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf):

> `after-sep` is the separation between title and text—vertical with hang, block, and display, and horizontal with runin, drop, wrap and ...margin. **By making the value negative**, you may
>   define an effective space of less than `\parskip`

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{before-sep}{after-sep}
```

You should be able to get the result you want by using this command to "undo" the additional spacing created after section headings when using `\setlength{\parskip}{<length>}` to adjust the inter-paragraph spacing.