# How to change separation space between paragraphs

Tags: parskip

I think it's probably unnecessary to think of changing the length of skips between paragraphs in the sense that the standard spacing of one skip defined by  the `parskip` package is always fine. But what about if I wanted two skips instead of one, or even worse if I wanted to change the length of the skip. I was thinking about modifying the value of `\parskip`, which apparently solves the problem. Truth is it also modifies my `enumerate` environments and I don't want that. Actually that makes me think that it may probably do the same thing with some other environments. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you load the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, you can control its spacing parameters explicitly. Should be able to make them independent of your modified `\parskip` length.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the "dont' do this" warning that you will most certainly receive, the `memoir` class allows you to change the regular `\parskip` value without messing up other things, by providing an `\abnormalparskip` macro:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\abnormalparskip{2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 6):

The package `parskip` does three things: (1) sets a zero `\parindent`, (2) sets a non-zero `\parskip`, and (3) adjusts the skips between list items to `\parindent`.

So, simply carry out (1) and (2), setting the `\parskip` length to stretchable glue, avoiding the need for the `parskip` package:

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{4\bigskipamount plus \smallskipamount minus \smallskipamount}
\begin{document}
Text\par
Text\par
Text\par
Text\par
\begin{enumerate}
\item One 
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}
Text\par
Text\par
Text\par
Text\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: somehow, neither the parskip package nor manually setting the parskip works for setting a custom skip in my case...

Comment: @Xerus "Your case" mean in another document? Then there is something  in conflict with that setting. Otherwise, you are doing something wrong to reproduce the example. Anyway, only you can check what could be.

Comment: indeed, I found it out after experimenting for a while, I set an org-mode flag incorrectly...