# Automatic line feed after paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I would like to have more space between the paragraphs, this automatically using usepackage or similar, for the whole document.

Would you have an idea how?

thank you

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} \begin{document}

Vestibulum posuere, quam sed bibendum posuere, orci est semper libero, nec congue tortor arcu eget velit. Mauris condimentum pulvinar condimentum. Sed suscipit elit tellus. Nunc vel fringilla massa. Aliquam sed velit lorem. Sed feugiat faucibus leo, ut iaculis eros ullamcorper vitae. Nulla bibendum, risus id imperdiet lobortis, dui eros varius justo, non lobortis leo orci sed nisi. Pellentesque et metus sem, ut ultrices dui. Phasellus neque nisi, commodo tempor dictum et, mattis ut magna. Donec est metus, sagittis pretium egestas eget, accumsan id ante.

Vestibulum posuere, quam sed bibendum posuere   Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus   Pellentesque nulla augue, volutpat vitae  

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam et ligula lacus. Maecenas tellus massa, tempus sit amet scelerisque sed, ultrices id massa. Donec massa augue, imperdiet in egestas luctus, hendrerit ut sem. Quisque pretium egestas arcu ut pellentesque. Vestibulum vestibulum eros quis dui condimentum hendrerit. Ut laoreet consectetur quam, non molestie sapien imperdiet porttitor. Nullam a purus non nisi feugiat euismod. Curabitur euismod odio at neque consectetur commodo. Sed tincidunt consequat mi, vitae tincidunt ipsum eleifend eu. Donec scelerisque risus purus. Etiam vitae est felis.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to change thew value of `\parskip`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240769/134574) or [this blog post](https://texblog.org/2012/11/07/correctly-typesetting-paragraphs-in-latex/) or [this guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting).

Comment: I tried \setlength{\parskip}{1\bigskipamount}, but it looks artificial a bit. I have feeling that it could look nicer.

Comment: What do you mean by "artificial"? For instance, if you use `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` it will look like an empty line between paragraphs. You can use a larger amount: `\setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip}` or a smaller amount: `\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}`, or any other amount you like: `\setlength{\parskip}{3.1415mm}`.

Comment: add `\usepackage{parskip}`  (better than setting `\parskip` "by hand")